# Flat file data analysis

Tags: linux, macos, file, analysis, flat

I have a **flat file** that consists of the following structure:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1  
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2  
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 F3 G3
```

This file has around **1 million rows**.

I would like to generate the following statistics:

1. **Number of rows** in the file.
2. **Number of unique records** in a particular **row** (e.g. B).
3. **Sort by row** F and create a file containing the **top n records in that row**.

What would be the best way of doing this analysis? I'm currently using **Mac OSX**, so a Linux/Mac solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty easy to do in bash (your mac command line shell).

Something like:

```
# 1. row count
wc -l filename

# 2. uniq count in col 1
cut -d " " -f 1 <filename> | sort | uniq | wc -l

# 3. top n uniq values in col 6, and their counts
cut -d " " -f 6 <filename> | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n <numrows>
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. One additional request - for (3) in addition to obtaining the value, it is also necessary to obtain the entire original row, e.g. "A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 F3 G3". Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Ian, in example 3 you are outputting the top N values in column 6. So for each output result  there will multiple rows in the original file with which it was associated. The solution would be to grep the original file for each of the result, but you may end up with more than <numrows>.  HTH.